# Laravel relationship pagination

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, relationship

I am trying to paginate the products please refer to the following code:

Here is my show.blade.php

```
    @foreach ($category->products as $product)
        <h2>{{ $product->name }}</h2>
    @endforeach
```

Here is my CategoriesController.php

```
    public function show($slug)
    {
       $category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

       return view('category.show', compact('category'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to paginate the products in the controller method and then pass the paginated result to the view.

```php
public function show($slug)
{
    $category = Category::with('products')->where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    $products = $category->products()->paginate(10);

    return view('category.show', compact('products'));
}
```

Then in blade view

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <h2>{{ $product->name }}</h2>
@endforeach

//To show the pagination links
{!! $products->links() !!}
```

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Pls remember to mark the answer as accepted/upvote for benefit of subsequent visitors